# Pointer, String Problem in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm using C for a class project for the first time after first learning C++, so syntax is killing me...  Basically, I need to store a string given by a function into a separate variable for later use.

I have an array of chars declared like this

```
char foo[];
```

A function that I'm given assigns a bunch of characters into this array (or pointers to characters?).  I can print out the actual string stored in foo like this

```
printf("%s", foo);
```

And I can store its address in a different variable like this

```
char *bar;

bar = &foo[0];

printf("%s", foo);
```

The full string is output just fine in both cases.  However, how can I store this string in a different variable?  If foo changes, then bar will no longer hold the string I need since it is just pointing to foo.  Anything I have thought of gives me compiler errors like

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Hopefully that's enough info.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I used the strdup method and it worked great.  Now I can get back to the real part of the assignment and quit worrying about syntax.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You need to copy the string.

Easiest way is with heap allocations:

```
char *bar = strdup(foo);
```

Don't forget to free that allocation when you are done with it:

```
free(bar);
```

If you don't want to use heap allocations, you can create a buffer on the stack and manually copy it in.  You do want to be careful that you don't overflow the buffer (and that your buffer is 0 terminated, strncpy won't do that for you if your src is longer then your dest):

```
char copy[SOMESIZE];
strncpy(copy, foo, sizeof(copy) - 1);
copy[sizeof(copy) - 1] = '\0';
```

If you have variable length array support, you can use that:

```
char copy[strlen(foo) + 1];
strcpy(copy, foo);
```

As [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48015/christoph) correctly noted in the comments, strdup is not part of the C standard.  If you're using Windows, you'll want to use [_strdup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc%28VS.80%29.aspx).  If you want to be absolutely portable, you can implement strdup quite easily:

```
char *strdup(const char *orig)
{
    char *copy = (char *)malloc(strlen(orig) + 1);
    if (copy != NULL)
        strcpy(copy, orig);

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: +1; keep in mind that `strdup()` is POSIX and not part of the ISO-C standard library, so you might have to re-implement it yourself if you want maximal portability

Comment: @Christoph - thanks.  Posix has been my primary development platform for so long I forget the difference.  Anyway, updated my answer to give some more info on that.

Comment: the glibc implementation ( http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2Acheckout%2A/libc/string/strdup.c?root=libc&content-type=text%2Fplain ) of `strdup()` uses `memcpy()` instead of `strcpy()`, which I'd expect to be slightly faster as you already had to determine the strings' length

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the string using `strncpy` or duplicate it using `strdup`:

```
char foo[] = "Hello World";
char* bar = strdup(foo);

foo[0] = 'B';
printf("%s", foo);
printf("%s", bar);

free(bar); // Don't forget to release the memory!
```

Prints:

```
Bello World
Hello World
```

Or, if you already have a string you want to copy into:

```
char foo[] = "Hello World";
char bar[] = "Goodbye Cruel World";

strncpy(bar, foo, sizeof(bar)-1); 

foo[0] = 'B';
printf("%s", foo);
printf("%s", bar);
```

Also rints:

```
Bello World
Hello World
```

The third argument to `strncpy` is the maximum number of characters to copy (to prevent overflow) Note that it is one less than the length of the `bar` buffer so that `bar` can be nul-terminated. Also note that `sizeof` only works here because `bar` is a local array. It does not work on `char*`, in that case you need to know the size externally, e.g.:

```
char foo[] = "Hello World";
size_t bar_len = 20;
char* bar = (char*)malloc(bar_len);

strncpy(bar, foo, bar_len-1); // CANNOT use sizeof(bar) here!

foo[0] = 'B';
printf("%s", foo);
printf("%s", bar);

free(bar); // Don't forget!
```

Comment: strncpy is not a good way to do this. strncpy *always* copies n characters, even if the string being copied is shorter, padding with 0 chars, wasting cycles. Additionally strncpy does not guarantee that the written string is 0 terminated, if the source string is longer than the length of the buffer it just gets truncated, without a terminating 0. And the -1 does not help here because malloc does not guarantee zeroed memory.

Answer (score -3):

use strcpy function to copy string to another variable.

```
char *myStringVar;

strcpy(myStringVar, your_Function_Returning_String() )
```

Allocate memory for myStringVar if returned string is out of scope.

EDIT:

```
char *myStringVar = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: `strcpy()` expects a buffer of sufficient size as the target, not an uninitialized pointer

Comment: -1: as you failed to allocate memory, this'll overwrite whatever random location the uninitialized variable points to

Comment: Still if i want to use strcpy only for the above problem, what changes should be made for strcpy to work properly ?

Comment: you need to make sure myStringVar points to valid memory.  You can change that to a stack allocation `char myStringVar[SIZE]` (although you need to be careful about buffer overflow) or you can allocate it on the heap `char *myStringVar = malloc(strlen(src) + 1)` (and you need to check that malloc does not return NULL).